# When diagonalizing a matrix does the order of the eigenvectors matter?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say I find the eigenvalues of some matrix $A$ and then use kernel computation to find an eigenbasis for each eigenvalue. Then $B = S^{-1}AS$, where $S$ is composed of the eigenbasis of each of the eigenvalues. Does the order in which I arrange the eigenbasis in $S$ matter? For example, say I find some eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ with corresponding eigenvector $v$ and $w$, respectively. Then does it matter if I say that $S = vw$ or $wv$?

It changes my diagonal matrix, but its still diagonal no?

Comment: $S$ will change depending on the order of the eigenvectors, but both forms are still good to use for diagonalization, as long as the corresponding diagonal matrix accounts for the switched columns (by switching order of eigenvalues).

Comment: Check out the right hand side question menu **Related**. You may find many interesting things there.